# Method object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written following code and it is not showing any alert.

```
var test = function(message) {
    this.show = function() {
        alert(message)
    }
}
(new test("hiii")).show();
(new test("helooo")).show();
```

When changed to following... 
Removed the bracket of - `(new test("hiii")).show();`

It shows both "hiii" and "helooo" alert.

Note: I did not make any changes to - `(new test("helooo")).show();`

```
var test = function(message) {
    this.show = function() {
        alert(message)
    }
}
new test("hiii").show(); // was(new test("hiii")).show();
(new test("helooo")).show();
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Both solutions work fine for me.

Comment: @zerkms I copied that first block of code into the Firefox debug console and it got an error.

Comment: @zerkms - you added the semicolon!!

Comment: No, the semicolon wasn't in [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31406797/1). @Tushar added the semicolon which I removed.

Comment: @BibinVenugopal it was not in the very initial revision of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, oddly enough, is with the fact that you left out the semicolon after your function expression:

```
var test = function(message){
    this.show = function() {
            alert(message)
    }
} // <-- missing semicolon
```

That means that the `( ... )` following the function expression is taken to be the argument list for a function call.

Add that missing semicolon and the first block of code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since semicolon is missing it will take as self invoking function expression with argument `new test("hiii")` so use it like this

```
var test = function(message) {
   this.show = function() {
       alert(message)
 }
};
(new test("hiii")).show();
(new test("helooo")).show();
```